# PHPUnit assert no method is called

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a ClassA that uses a ServiceB. In a certain case, ClassA should end up not invoking any methods of ServiceB. I now want to test this and verity no methods are indeed called.

This can be done as follows:

```
$classA->expects( $this->never() )->method( 'first_method' );
$classA->expects( $this->never() )->method( 'second_method' );
...
```

Is there a way to simply state "no method should be called on this object" rather then having to specify a restriction for each method?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yes, it's quite simple, try this:

```
$classA->expects($this->never())->method($this->anything());
```

Comment: Nowadays you should likely use `$classA->expects(self::never())->method(self::anything())`;

Answer (score 3):

You can use method `MockBuilder::disableAutoReturnValueGeneration`.

For example, in your test overwrite default `TestCase::getMockBuilder`:

```php
    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @return MockBuilder
     */
    public function getMockBuilder($className): MockBuilder
    {
        // this is to make sure, that not-mocked method will not be called
        return parent::getMockBuilder($className)
            ->disableAutoReturnValueGeneration();
    }
```

Advantages:

- all your mocks won't be expected to call anything than mocked methods. No need to bind `->expects(self::never())->method(self::anything())` to all of them
- you still can set new mocks. After `->expects(self::never())->method(self::anything())` you can't

Works for PhpUnit v7.5.4 (and probably, later ones).

Answer (score 0):

you could also mock a method and a data provider, and make sure it never is called. without making any assertions, because it is not called, it means it has passed the test.

```
<?php
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataProvider
     */
    public function checkSomethingIsDisabled( $message, $config, $expected)
    {
        $debugMock = $this->getMockBuilder('APP_Class_Name')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('_helper'))
            ->getMock();

        $debugMock = $this->getPublicClass($debugMock);
        $debugMock->_config = $config;
        $viewContent = new stdClass;
        $debugMock->_functionToTest($viewContent);
    }

    public function dataProvider()
    {
        return [
                'dataset'=>
                    [
                        'message' => 'Debug Disabled',
                        'config' => (object) array(
                            'values' => (object) array(
                                'valueThatWhenFalseDoesntExecuteFunc'=> false
                            )
                        ),
                        // in a probably needed complimentary "imaginary" test we probably  
                        // will have the valueThatWhenFalseDoesntExecuteFunc set to true and on
                        // expected more information to handle and test.
                        'expected' => null
                    ]
                ];
    }
```