# PHP Unit assert no method is called except some

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Similar question to this: [PHPUnit assert no method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745032/phpunit-assert-no-method-is-called)

How to assert that no method is called except some that I can define? The following test doesn't pass, because PHPUnit validates all expects().

```
//Here assert that only 'firstMethodToBeCalled' and 'secondMethodToBeCalled' are called, and no more
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->never())
    ->method($this->anything());
$mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('firstMethodToBeCalled');
$mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('secondMethodToBeCalled');
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer since neither of them worked, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('firstMethodToBeCalled');
$mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('secondMethodToBeCalled');
$mock->expects($this->never())
    ->method(
        $this->logicalAnd(
            $this->logicalNot($this->equalTo('firstMethodToBeCalled')),
            $this->logicalNot($this->equalTo('secondMethodToBeCalled')),
        )
    );
```