# How to make PHPUnit mock fail on calling unconfigured methods?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Is it possible to have PHPUnit fail when any unconfigured method is called on a mock object?

Example;

```
$foo = $this->createMock(Foo::class);
$foo->expects($this->any())->method('hello')->with('world');

$foo->hello('world');
$foo->bye();
```

This test will succeed. I would like it to fail with

```
Foo::bye() was not expected to be called.
```

---

P.S. The following would work, but this means I'd have to list all configured methods in the callback. That's not a suitable solution.

```
$foo->expects($this->never())
    ->method($this->callback(fn($method) => $method !== 'hello'));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPUnit Mock Objects never expect by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624938/phpunit-mock-objects-never-expect-by-default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done by disabling auto-return value generation.

```
$foo = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
    ->disableAutoReturnValueGeneration()
    ->getMock();

$foo->expects($this->any())->method('hello')->with('world');

$foo->hello('world');
$foo->bye();
```

This will result in

```
Return value inference disabled and no expectation set up for Foo::bye()
```

*Note that it's not required for other methods (like `hello`) to define a return method.*

Comment: This is an undocumented feature but can be found by looking at the source code of PHPUnit. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/InvocationHandler.php#L144

Comment: You can also make this automatic by overriding the `getMockBuilder()` of your test case. like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551436/1664083